# Why is fgetc returning ffffffff instead of actual data in file?

Tags: c, image, image-processing, computer-science

I am writing a program to read a hex image file, and write a part of it to another file.

When I read it, some part of the file is read properly, but somewhere in between it starts reading and returning *FF* instead of actual hex data on and off in the file.

I have used `unsigned char ch` for `ch=fgetc(sourceImageFile)`

I don't understand where I'm going wrong, and why it's returning long lines of *FF* in between. Please Help Me.
Also I've kept one input file as .txt to be able to open it and debug.

This is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
  FILE* source;
  FILE* sr, * sg, * sb;
  int i = 1;

  source = fopen("file.L-4", "r");
  sr = fopen("red.img", "wb+");
  sg = fopen("green.img", "wb+");
  sb = fopen("blue.txt", "wb+");

  fseek(source, 540, SEEK_SET);
  printf("\nDone phew!\n");
  unsigned char ch;
  int l = 1;
  unsigned char buf[10];
  while (l <= 5279)
  {

    fseek(source, 32, SEEK_CUR);
    i = 1;
    while (i <= 4919 && l < 5280)
    {
      ch = fgetc(source);

      sprintf(buf, "%02x ", ch);
      fputs(buf, sb);
      i++;
    } //BLUE done
    l++;
    //fseek(source,9902,SEEK_CUR);


    fseek(source, 32, SEEK_CUR);
    i = 1;
    while (i <= 4919 && l < 5280)
    {
      ch = fgetc(source);

      sprintf(buf, "%02x ", ch);
      fputs(buf, sg);
      i++;
    } //GREEEN done
    l++;

    fseek(source, 32, SEEK_CUR);
    i = 1;
    while (i <= 4919 && l < 5280)
    {
      ch = fgetc(source);

      sprintf(buf, "%02x ", ch);
      fputs(buf, sr);
      i++;
    } //RED done
    l++;


    //printf("%d  ",l);
  }
  printf("\nthis is done too!\n");
  fclose(sr);
  fclose(sg);
  fclose(sb);
  fclose(source);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fgetc` returns `int` not `char`. This is because it returns `EOF` for end of file or error. `EOF` is usually`-1` or all `F`s. You have magic numbers everywhere which is not only very bad coding form but also might be resulting in reading past the end of the file. Check what the read offset is when you get `EOF`.

Comment: You should format your code properly. It's difficult to work with poorly formatted code.

Comment: And minimize it so we don't spend time looking at stuff that works.

Comment: Thanks I'll work over that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just paraphrasing what @kaylum already told you. `fgetc()` returns an `int` while you are storing the result in a `unsigned char`.  This means you cannot tell from `ch` if you read `0xff` or EOF (EOF is defined as -1 on my system, and in 2's complement that is `0xff`).  As you are processing binary data you want to change the type.  Always check the return value!

```
int ch;
...
if((ch = fgetc(source)) == EOF) {
   // nothing more to read
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining I'll work over it again

Comment: Turns out I had opened output file in write binary mode but input source file was in normal read text mode. Changed both to binary mode now. I've added checkpoints to check for EOF. But still I'm getting a few FFs in the files here and there..